# How to deserialize 2d array using json

Tags: c#

How to deserialize JSON containing array or arrays?

```
{"InlineKeyboard":[
    [{"Text":"sometext","Url":"someurl"},{"Text":"sometext","Url":"someurl"}],
    [{"Text":"sometext","Url":"someurl"},{"Text":"sometext","Url":"someurl","}]
]}
```

That's my classes I created :

```
public class InlineKeyboard 
{
    [JsonProperty("InlineKeyboard")]
    public List<Keyboard> keyboards { get; set; }
}

public class Keyboard 
{
    [JsonProperty("Text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

That's how I tried to deserialize :

```
var keyboard = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<InlineKeyboard>>(replymarkup);
```

Error:

> Because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])

Note that what I'm calling 2d array is not really 2d array (as in `int[,]`) but rather some usage of `List<...>`.

Comment: Do you want to flatten array of arrays into list or you are looking to get List of List or you are actually asking how to get 2d array as result? (I assumed with my edit that you are looking for `List<List<...>>` - feel free to update the question or even revert the edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json in question is not valid (has extra `,"` in the end), but if you fix that you can deserialize it with:

```
public class InlineKeyboard
{
    [JsonProperty("InlineKeyboard")]
    public List<List<Keyboard>> keyboards { get; set; }
}
public class Keyboard
{
    [JsonProperty("Text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

var keyboard = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InlineKeyboard>(replymarkup);
```

Your root json element is an object, not an array, so you should deserialize to an object(`InlineKeyboard`), not `List` of objects. But `InlineKeyboard` is array of arrays, so you need to change `InlineKeyboard.keyboards` property type accordingly.

Comment: First thanks for the fast reply bro ! 
I tried this code and no errors finally ! but unfortunately 
the "keyboard" that i insert the deserialization is null :/

Comment: @OnePixel can you add a reproducer? Cause it [works for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hb9V4X) with corrected json form question.

Comment: brooo !! you made my week !! the problem was that i used other library of json before that and the url and text was with lower case .. so i changed it and its work !! bro i tried to fix it a whole day ..... youre a legend thank you very much !!!!